# rrdtool xport filename with spaces

Tags: bash, whitespace, rrdtool

I'm trying to call rrdtool xport command on arbitrary number of files, so I'm writing a script that reads in the rrd file names and builds the DEF argument. The problem is some of the rrd files have whitespaces in them, i.e. "foo bar.rrd" (-_-)...and when the DEF argument is generated, it looks something like this:

```
DEF:a=foo bar.rrd:sum:AVERAGE
```

and when this is passed in to the rrdtool command, it generates an error saying "problems reading database name". I also have tried inserting the escape character ("\") before whitespace so it would look like "foo\ bar.rrd", but when this is run in bash, it still produces same error, whereas when I echo the command and copy paste it on the prompt and run it then it works fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put quotes around the whole thing

```
"DEF:a=foo bar.rrd:sum:AVERAGE"
```

rrdtool should be fine with the spaces.